# An unusual source of inspiration?

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, connect-wall

In each row of the table below, a word* is missing (in Column B). This word can be paired separately with the two either side of it (in Columns A and C) to form another English word or phrase, preserving the column order. (For example, BOTTLE could be inserted between BLUE and BANK to make BLUEBOTTLE and BOTTLE BANK.)

Once deduced, these sixteen words can be divided into two equal groups, where words in the same group share a particular connection. The two groups are themselves closely related - you need to explain how.

> **TASK: Identify the sixteen words* represented by question mark icons. Divide them into two groups of eight connected words, and explain the three-word phrase that connects these two groups.**

<sup>** NB One 'word' is actually a two-word unit.*</sup>

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| SIXTEEN | ? | TICK |
| CABLE | ? | PET |
| COPY | ? | FLAP |
| GLASS | ? | FAN |
| CHECKPOINT | ? | BROWN |
| HARD | ? | RED |
| PONTYPOOL | ? | TRENCH |
| STEP | ? | STITCH |
| INTER | ? | KUNDERA |
| NEW YORK | ? | MINUTE |
| COCKTAIL | ? | ANIMAL |
| TIGHT | ? | BRIDGE |
| BARNEY | ? | PILE |
| TOILET | ? | IBIZA |
| HAWAIIAN | ? | TAIL |
| GREEN | ? | LEAVES |

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer phrase is

> Right Said Fred

The missing words, sorted into two groups are:

> ```
> First group:
> GREEN       tea      LEAVES
> CHECKPOINT  charlie  BROWN
> SIXTEEN     candles  TICK
> TOILET      seat     IBIZA
> GLASS       ceiling  FAN
> TIGHT       rope     BRIDGE
> STEP        ladder   STITCH
> BARNEY      rubble   PILE
>
> Second group:
> HAWAIIAN    shirt    TAIL
> INTER       milan    KUNDERA
> NEW YORK    new york MINUTE
> PONTYPOOL   japan    TRENCH
> COCKTAIL    party    ANIMAL
> CABLE       car      PET
> HARD        hat      RED
> COPY        cat      FLAP
> ```

Thanks to Jeremy Dover for supplying the two that I was missing.

The groups are:

> 1. Words occurring in the lyrics of [Right Said Fred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_Said_Fred_(song)), a comedy song by the legend that is [Bernard Cribbins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernard_Cribbins).
>  2. Words occurring in the lyrics of [I'm Too Sexy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27m_Too_Sexy), by [Right Said Fred](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_Said_Fred). More specifically, the words are things the lyrics say they're too sexy for. The band actually took their name from Bernard Cribbins' song, which is a strange source of inspiration for a band name.

Comment: NEW YORK _ MINUTE fills with rot13(arj lbex), and fittingly PONTYPOOL _ TRENCH is filled with rot13(wncna).

Comment: @JeremyDover Thank you! I'm kicking myself for the first one. I've edited those answers in.

Comment: Great job, Jaap :) You can in fact be even more specific about the words in your first group... (not that anything you've said is wrong) Also, can you explain the title? I wasn't talking about my own inspiration here... :)

Comment: I wouldn't kick myself...was very clever on Stiv's part.

Comment: Exactly right. I heartily approve of your use of 'the legend that is' - one of my faves - and this fact is one of my favourite pieces of trivia; it just seems so at odds that rot13(gur onaq gung tnir hf 'V'z Gbb Frkl', 'Erynk', naq bguref fubhyq unir gnxra gurve anzr sebz n purreshy, vaabprag pbzrql ahzore!).